# displaying a listbox after dialog confirm

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have a datatable of users which contains a column with a delete button.
what i want is when i click on the button a confirm dialog shows up and ask for confirmation.
after the confirmation i want to check a condition if it's true another dialog shows up containig a listbox.
this is my view.xhtml:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable value="#{PersonnelMB.lstp}" var="h" resizableColumns="true" id="pdt" paginator="true" rows="10" widgetVar="ptable">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:outputPanel style="align-content: right:all;">
            <h:outputText value="Recherche:" />
            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('ptable').filter();" style="width:150px;height: 28px;" placeholder="Enter keyword"/>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </f:facet>
    <p:column sortBy="#{h.id}" filterBy="#{h.id}" style="text-align: center;">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Id"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{h.id}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column sortBy="#{h.prenom}" filterBy="#{h.prenom}" style="text-align: center">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Prenom"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{h.prenom}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column sortBy="#{h.nom}" filterBy="#{h.nom}" style="text-align: center">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Nom"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{h.nom}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column filterBy="#{h.email}" >
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Email"></h:outputText><br/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{h.email}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column  >
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Actions"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <p:commandButton type="button" icon="ui-icon-trash" style="background-color:#f20d0d;" onclick="confirmation.show()"/>
        <p:confirmDialog message="Are you sure?" header="Confirmation" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation">
          <p:commandButton value="Yes" oncomplete="confirmation.hide()"  actionListener="#{PersonnelMB.supprimerPerso}" />
          <p:commandButton value="Not" onclick="confirmation.hide()" type="button" />
        </p:confirmDialog>
```

```
    </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call another dialog (lets suppose its widgetVar="anotherDialog") from your managed bean like this:

```
    public void supprimerPerso() {
    ...
    if (condition) {
        RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        requestContext.execute("PF('anotherDialog').show()");
    }
}
```

Note: 1. If you do not pass any parameters to the above method, remember to add braces to method call : actionListener="#{PersonnelMB.supprimerPerso **()** }".
Braces are omitted when parameters are passed.
2. Enable selection and use the selected record for deletion. This makes it easier.

Check [showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/listbox.xhtml) for showing listbox in "anotherDialog". Something like this:

```
<p:dialog header="Selected User for Deletion" widgetVar="anotherDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade"  resizable="false">
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="display" columnClasses="label,output">
        <h:outputText value="Employee ID:" />
        <h:outputText value="#{PersonnelMB.selectedUser.id}" />

        <h:outputText value="Employee Name:" />
        <h:outputText value="#{PersonnelMB.selectedUser.nom}" />

    </p:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
```